# How to recover previous save of a document?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I recover a previous save of a Microsoft Word document?

As I work I hit ctrl-s frequently. My few most recent saves overwrote some text I now want to recover from a couple saves ago.

How can I recover that text?

Comment: If version history is enabled,  Go to File > Info > Version History and select where you want to restore from.  I suggest saving off another copy (outside of word itself) before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential ways to restore:

If you still have the document open, you can simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> your way back into the previous state that you wanted.

Most applications of word have history enable so going to the upper tab on File>Info>Version History should have your previous state there as well.

Comment: Microsoft Word does not have versioning built in. (It did a long time ago, but that did not work. See http://www.gmayor.com/SaveVersionsAdd-In.htm.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only if your document was stored on OneDrive or SharePoint. Then you would access Versions.

If you have not closed the document, Ctrl+Z (Undo) to take you back.

You may have some kind of backup software on your computer that is making backups frequently enough to help you, but this would be unusual.

Which operating system are you using?

For future use, look into some sort of versioning software. Here is a free Add-In from Word MVP Graham Mayor: [Save Numbered Versions](http://www.gmayor.com/SaveVersionsAdd-In.htm)